# Tricky : Array of controls dynamically created causing problems

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I put "Tricky" in the title because I'm aware that it will be hard to understand precisely what I want but I'll try to be clear.

I have a textBox with an event for TextChange which allow me to create the number of texboxes the user want (we will call it *tChange*).

Here is a part of the code for this event :

```
int tester;
bool flag = false;
if (!Int32.TryParse(tChange.Text, out tester))
{
    flag = false;
    return;
}
else
{
    num = Convert.ToInt16(tChange.Text);
    flag = true;
}
if (flag == true)
{
    if (num >= 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
           this.Size = new Size(590, 225 + 105 * i);
           textBoxesQ[i] = new TextBox();
           this.Controls.Add(textBoxesQ[i]);
           textBoxesQ[i].Size = new Size(45, 20);
           textBoxesQ[i].Location = new Point(25, 100 + 100 * i - 1);  
        }
    }
}
```

So the user enter the value and everything is OK. If he wants to change the number in the *tChange*, no problem too! The form is resize and the TextBoxes are created. **However** if he does this (change the value of *tChange*), everything goes wrong! Errors like

> Index out of range

or I can't get the values from the TextBoxes etc..

I started thinking that the TexBoxes were created in front of the previous ones and the error came from this, so I tried to put the new ones to front, bring the old ones to front but none worked..

```
textBoxesQ[i].BringToFront();
textBoxesQ[i].SendToBack();
```

I also tried to delete the old ones before creating the new but I think that my code was wacky and it didn't work at all.

```
textBoxesQ[i].Dispose();
```

**EDIT :** As @Dr. Stitch said, It may come from not reinitializing the TextBoxes each time the text in *tChange* is changed. Now I just need to figure out how to make it happen.

Comment: change for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) to for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)

Comment: I don't think that it is the problem. I encounter the issue if for exemple I put 2 in _tChange_ and then 3, the first two TextBoxes won't work.

Comment: the issue is with the textBoxesQ array, you should reinitialize the array: TextBoxes[] textBoxesQ  = new TextBoxes[num] each time the num value is change. :)

Comment: is this a different array textBoxesPLT[i]?

Comment: Yeah I edit that, that was a mistake. It seems to be the issue but when I want to be able to access it from several functions so I don't know how to reinitialize it in a function and then use it from others.. (I'm a newbie)

Comment: You need to remove the old textboxes. Please show what you tried, we cannot help you with "didn't work, don't show".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do three things when the number changes:

- Remove any existing textboxes
- Create a new array with the new size, and save a reference to that new array into your field (`textBoxesQ`)
- Initialize the array

So something like:

```
if (textBoxesQ != null)
{
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxesQ)
    {
        Controls.Remove(textBox);
    }
}
textBoxesQ = new TextBox[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox
    {
       Size = new Size(45, 20);
       Location = new Point(25, 100 + 100 * i - 1);  
    };
    Controls.Add(textBox);
    textBoxesQ[i] = textBox;
}
```

Comment: It's working! Very nice, I should try to learn how to code properly one day! Anyway thank you @Jon